# Need help determining which statistical test to use

Tags: t-test, multivariate-analysis

I am an MD attempting to do my own statistics for a project I have been working on. I have 3 groups (which are comprised of combinations of 2 categorical variables), lets call the groups A+B-, A+B+, and A-B+ (note: I do not have a A-B- group). My outcome measure is continuous. My initial thought was to perform a t-test between each group in pairs (therefore I would have 3 p values for each outcome measure). Someone with a little more statistical prowess tipped me to the possibility of a multivariate analysis, which I have little understanding of at this point. Any help/clarification as to which analysis in this situation is appropriate for would be tremendously appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you specify what exactly you're trying to measure from your groups. Do you have a hypothesis for example?

Comment: Same here. It sounds as a simple one-way ANOVA with post-hoc contrasts with a Tukey test. Are you using R?

Comment: My groups are comprised of 2 surgical variables, any my outcome is blood loss. My hypothesis is that blood loss is the most in one of the groups, medium in another, and lowest in the final group. Thanks again!

Comment: Which significance test is appropriate depends on more factors than are described in your question. I have put the all the factors that are relevant in the form of questions in a in-browser tool. This will probably help -> [7questionsorless to find the correct statistical test] (https://www.thesishulp.nl/anova-t-toets-of-regressie-analyse/)  

In essence your research design in combination with the types of data you collected (categorical, interval etc) per variable (both indep. and dep.) and whether you data complies with some assumptions regarding normality (assumption pre-tests).